# How can I fix block grid reload issues in admin?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, search

[image]

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module_name\Block\Adminhtml\Statement\Edit\Tab;

class Products extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{

    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    protected $catalogStatus;

    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Adolmedia\MerchantCatalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\CatalogStatus $catalogStatus,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->catalogStatus = $catalogStatus;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('custom_product_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at', 'desc');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

        $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(
            '*'
        );
        $this->setCollection($productCollection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'filter_index' => 'entity_id',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'filter_index' => 'name',
                'index' => 'name',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'type_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Type'),
                'filter_index' => 'type_id',
                'index' => 'type_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'filter_index' => 'price',
                'index' => 'price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'edit',
            [
                'header' => __('Action'),
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => [
                    [
                        'caption' => __('Edit'),
                        'url' => [
                            'base' => '*/*/edit',
                            'params' => ['store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store')]
                        ],
                        'field' => 'id'
                    ],
                ],
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            '*/*/edit',
            ['id' => $row->getId()]
        );
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('entity_ids');
        return $this;
    }

}
```

when i am trying to use filter it displays like this

Comment: can you add your module somewhere for an easy fix?

Comment: sorry i didn't get you clearly .. do i need to post entire flow of this grid????

Comment: Yes, not a full module, only that part that will easily generate what you looking for. because this is custom not default magento so this takes more time to create module, grid, installer, edit etc.

Comment: yes edited my post with my files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Sections/Products.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Sections;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory;

class Products extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $resultLayoutFactory;


    /**
     * Sections constructor.
     *
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Page section grid
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $resultLayout */
        $resultLayout = $this->resultLayoutFactory->create();
        return $resultLayout;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/yourname_yourname_products.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <container name="root" label="Root">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Block\Edit\Tab\Products" name="adminhtml.sections.edit.tab.products"/>
        </container>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Sections/Edit/Tab/Products.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sections\Edit\Tab;

class Products extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{

    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    protected $catalogStatus;

    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('custom_product_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at', 'desc');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

        $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(
            '*'
        );
        $this->setCollection($productCollection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'filter_index' => 'entity_id',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'filter_index' => 'name',
                'index' => 'name',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'type_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Type'),
                'filter_index' => 'type_id',
                'index' => 'type_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'filter_index' => 'price',
                'index' => 'price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'edit',
            [
                'header' => __('Action'),
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => [
                    [
                        'caption' => __('Edit'),
                        'url' => [
                            'base' => '*/*/edit',
                            'params' => ['store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store')]
                        ],
                        'field' => 'id'
                    ],
                ],
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('yourid/sections/products', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            '*/*/edit',
            ['id' => $row->getId()]
        );
    }

}
```

**Note:** *edit xml as your own module, controller and grid path too.*

Comment: public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('yourid/sections/products', ['_current' => true]);
    } actually where should i create this file

Comment: This is actually url. Should location app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Sections/Products.php. yourid is your admin route, that you define routes.xml

Comment: public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('merchant_payments/statement/grid', ['_current' => true]);
    }

Comment: <?php
namespace Vendor\MerchantPayments\Controller\Adminhtml\Statement;

class Grid extends \Vendor\MerchantPayments\Controller\Adminhtml\Statement
{

}

Comment: actually when i click search button spinner appears and redirected to someother page

Comment: after reback got error message like this 'Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.'

Comment: Something wrong with your module. This is simple fix but sorry it's really hard to guess.

Comment: Hi Sohel, Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/262961/60509 It's really helpful for me, If you solve my question.

Comment: \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended this class is deprecated

Comment: Yes. Magento deprecated this and encourage to use UI Component

Comment: But is it possible to add ui component listing in edit page with dynamic filters

Comment: Yes, possible. Ui component so much flexible

Comment: sohel thank you for all your response .. Actually i did small mistake in my grid controller i have failed to extend parent class thats the reason.. Really helpful ..Thank you ...